# How to update an existing Excel file with multiple sheets using PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell, export-to-excel, import-from-excel

How can I update an existing Excel file with multiple sheets using PowerShell.

I'm using the below code for an Excel file with a single sheet, but need to do something similar to an Excel file with multiple sheets (Sheet names are known).
So I need to import all existing sheets, update each sheet individually and then save all changed sheets to a new multi-sheet Excel file.

```
Import-Module activedirectory

# Read existing Excel file
$xlsx = import-excel 'D:\users.xlsx'

# Get the properties
$Properties = [Collections.Generic.List[Object]]$xlsx[0].psobject.properties.Name

# Add new columns. Position 6 & 7
$Properties.Insert(6, "Name")
$Properties.Insert(7, "Team")

# Obtain name and team from AD for every user (ID)
foreach ($row in $xlsx)
{   
   $user = Get-AD -CN $row.ID

   $row | Add-Member -Name 'Name' -Value $user[0]  -MemberType NoteProperty 
   $row | Add-Member -Name 'Team' -Value $user[1]  -MemberType NoteProperty
}

# Create a new Excel file
$xl = $xlsx | Select-Object -Property $Properties | Export-Excel 'D\new_users.xlsx' -Append -WorksheetName "USERS"

$Sheet = $xl.Workbook.Worksheets["USERS"]

Close-ExcelPackage $xl –Show
```

Any help much approciated!

Comment: The logic for each spreadsheet is the same ? Or is the question about how you can iterate over the data of each spreadsheet ?

Comment: How to import all sheets, iterate over the sheets, update and save.
Currently it's only importing the first sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over each spreadsheet with `Get-ExcelSheetInfo` then use `Import-Excel` with the `-WorksheetName` parameter. If you want to append new columns to each spreadsheet then something like this should work:

```bash
Get-ExcelSheetInfo 'D:\users.xlsx' | ForEach-Object {
    $xlsx = Import-Excel $_.Path -WorksheetName $_.Name

    foreach ($row in $xlsx) {
        # do stuff with `$row`
    }

    $xlsx | Export-Excel -Path $_.Path -WorksheetName $_.Name
}
```

---

Adding a simple example appending columns to an Excel file with 2 Spreadsheets.

First we create a test `test.xlsx` file with the `Id` of the first 4 processes on `Processes` Spreadsheet and the `Name` of the first 4 services on `Services` Spreadsheet:

```bash
Get-Process | Select-Object Id -First 4 |
    Export-Excel .\test.xlsx -WorksheetName Processes

Get-Service | Select-Object Name -First 4 |
    Export-Excel .\test.xlsx -WorksheetName Services
```

Looking, at the current file:

```bash
Get-ExcelSheetInfo .\test.xlsx | ForEach-Object {
    '- Sheet Name: ' + $_.Name | Out-Host
    Import-Excel $_.Path -WorksheetName $_.Name -AsText Id | Out-Host
}

# Outputs:

- Sheet Name: Processes

Id
--
6392
3964
3604
7708

- Sheet Name: Services

Name
----
AarSvc_9af2c
AJRouter
ALG
AppIDSvc
```

Now, for the `Processes` Spreadsheet append columns **Id, ProcessName and HandleCount** in that order and for the `Services` Spreadsheet append columns **Status, Name and DisplayName**.

```bash
foreach ($sheet in Get-ExcelSheetInfo .\test.xlsx) {
    if ($sheet.Name -eq 'Processes') {
        # here we handle the logic for the processes sheet
        Import-Excel $sheet.Path -WorksheetName $sheet.Name -AsText Id |
            ForEach-Object { Get-Process -Id $_.Id } |
            Select-Object Id, ProcessName, HandleCount |
            Export-Excel $sheet.Path -WorksheetName $sheet.Name
    }
    elseif ($sheet.Name -eq 'Services') {
        # here we handle the logic for the services sheet
        Import-Excel $sheet.Path -WorksheetName $sheet.Name |
            ForEach-Object { Get-Service -Name $_.Name } |
            Select-Object Status, Name, DisplayName |
            Export-Excel $sheet.Path -WorksheetName $sheet.Name
    }
}
```

Lastly, check how the result looks like:

```bash
Get-ExcelSheetInfo .\test.xlsx | ForEach-Object {
    '- Sheet Name: ' + $_.Name | Out-Host
    Import-Excel $_.Path -WorksheetName $_.Name -AsText Id, HandleCount | Out-Host
}

# Outputs:

- Sheet Name: Processes

Id   ProcessName          HandleCount
--   -----------          -----------
6392 ApplicationFrameHost 271
3964 AsHidSrv             115
3604 AsLdrSrv             134
7708 ATKOSD2              197

- Sheet Name: Services

Status  Name         DisplayName
------  ----         -----------
Stopped AarSvc_9af2c Agent Activation Runtime_9af2c
Stopped AJRouter     AllJoyn Router Service
Stopped ALG          Application Layer Gateway Service
Stopped AppIDSvc     Application Identity
```

Comment: The format (column names and order) of each sheet is not identical. 
How can I make a sheet active and make changes for that specific sheet?

Comment: @JohnDoe making the sheet active is shown in the code itself, `$xlsx` will be an array of objects representing a spreadsheet on each loop iteration. making changes to that specific spreadsheet is shown in the `Export-Excel` line of the loop body. you're asking a very broad question.

Comment: Between the `$xlsx` and the `foreach loop` I still have to make a selection for which sheet I want to make the change (add extra columns). 
Now the on each loop returns all rows of all sheets. 
Maybe I'm overlooking something or not understanding it properly. Sorry about that.

Comment: @JohnDoe that would require chained `if` conditions or a `switch` inside the `ForEach-Object` loop that determines what logic should be followed for each sheet (`$_.Name`) but that logic is something that you need to handle, I don't have access to your excel file and don't know what changes you want to make to each specific sheet (hence why the broad question). I could add a minimal example if you think that can help.

Comment: If you would be willing to make a small example, I would greatly appreciate it.
If I can have a sheet active then I can make the changes. I don't yet understand how I can detect and activate the different sheets and then make changes to them.

Comment: @JohnDoe example added

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort you have made for me. Very much appreciated!